# Process.Start parameter containing spaces has problems on XP?

Tags: c#, .net

The following code snippet runs nicely on windows vista or windows 7, but not on XP:

```
String filename = System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName(), ".html");
[...write file...]
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("excel.exe", "\"" + filename + "\"");
```

Problem is, on Windows XP the `filename` contains spaces ("c:\documents and settings..."), so on XP Excel just shows the error "can't open c:\documents.xls".

On Windows Vista and 7 it even works when I set the path/filename to something containing spaces.

Is there a way to change the parameters so it will open on windows XP, too, or will I have to change the temp directory on all my clients computers?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `'` instead of `"` ?

Comment: Have you tried on a different XP machine? I've seen some XP machines with the DDE and open files broken, so that you cannot open the file in XP even from the commandline or windows explorer.

Comment: Whoops, Leppie, I'll check that, thanks!

Comment: @Leppie, no, using single quotes start does not even work anymore on modern systems. Double quotes is it.

Comment: @leppie: Double quotes are valid characters to quote strings on the shell. This should work.

Comment: @Sam: Why does the error state *documents.xls*? Shouldn't there be an html extension at least? Are there any macros/addins running on startup in Excel which can't handle spaces in the file path? Have you tried to open the temporary file manually in Excel?

Comment: @0xA3, Excel only gets the parameter until the first space (c:\documents), and since no extension is present, it adds the default extension. No macros/addins present, the startup works if I use a directory without spaces.
Opening the file manually works, too.

Comment: Do you have the same version of Excel on both machines?

Comment: And do you have the same version of your application on both machines? And are you actually starting the version of your application that you think you're starting?

Comment: @Regent, of course not. But if I put the file into some fixed dir (no spaces) instead of the temp dir, it works. On the very same comp.
I know I'm using the right program, since using a different dir worked (if I'd use the wrong program, the dir would not have changed).

Comment: Your code definitely works with Excel (2003) on Windows XP. Did you try this on a clean system? Other things you can do: Repair your Office installation, disable all add-ins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Excel on my WinXP x64 SP2 but notepad worked even without quotes:

```
string filename = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetTempFileName(), ".html");
File.AppendAllText(filename, "Test");

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", filename);
```

But if it is not working for you I think it is worth trying to set working directory and provide only the file name:

```
string filename = .Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetTempFileName(), ".html");
File.AppendAllText(filename, "Test");

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
{
    Arguments = Path.GetFileName(filename),
    WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename),
    FileName = "excel.exe"
});
```

Comment: I just copied your first example (changing `notepad.exe` back to `excel.exe`) and ran it. Works fine on 32 bit WinXP too.

Comment: And your temp directory does contain spaces? Or was it changed to some path without spaces?

Comment: These are the files I get, as expected :-
C:\Documents and Settings\myname\Local Settings\Temp\tmp15.tmp (0 bytes)
C:\Documents and Settings\myname\Local Settings\Temp\tmp15.html (4 bytes)

Comment: @Sam: It does contain spaces. I just checked and it was `C:\Documents and Settings\Regent\Local Settings\Temp\tmpCF2.html`

Comment: @Sam: But have you tried setting `WorkingDirectory` as in example in this answer?

Comment: @Regent, I have not found time yet, but it looks very promising to me, so I definitely will!

Comment: Setting the workingdirectory did the trick, thanks for the idea!!

Answer (score 9):

Try using:

```
Process excelProcess = new Process();

excelProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "excel.exe";
excelProcess.StartInfo.Aguments = "\"" + filename + "\"";

excelProcess.Start();
```

I know this code works with spaces in the filename.

Comment: Does your code work on XP with spaces?
On Vista/7 my version with the FileName and Arguments on the constructor does work, too.

Comment: @Sam - yes - I did double check it just to be sure though :)

Answer (score 2):

If `excel.exe` is the default executable for the `xls` file extension on your system, you can just use:

```
Process.Start(filename)
```

Alternatively you could try to find the short 8.3 style path name and use that as the argument.

Comment: *cough* if you'd have read my example, you would have noticed that my file extension is *not* xls, but html. But I still want excel to open the file, not the browser, so I can't use your version of the call.

Comment: Any clues how to get the 8.3 filename from the path/name I got from GetTempFileName?

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Actually I did read your question and example, just did not bother to scroll.

Comment: All the examples I can find use P/Invoke e.g. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/crajesh1981/RajeshPage103142006044841AM/RajeshPage1.aspx