# How to pass a string with spaces in it as start arguments for a program

Tags: c#, process

I have a console project which I want to start with some parameters `argc`. I want to pass to it a path from my computer, let's say `C:\\My Folder`. How can I pass the spaces?

When I try to read it I obtain something like `C:\\My`. I've read that I can pass them by using `"`. If so, how can I pass those to a string (`"C:\My Folder"`) because I am start this program by using the `Process.Start` and `ProcessStartInfo` commands?

Comment: Have you tried `"\"C:\\My Folder\""` i.e. putting escaped quotes inside the string?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Wrap the argument in double quotes:

```
"c:\My Folder\some.exe" /a="this is an argument"
```

As a string passed to Process.Start:

```
process.StartInfo.Aguments = "\"this is an argument\"";
```

Check out [this post & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299444/process-start-parameter-containing-spaces-has-problems-on-xp) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use delimited string. Using delimited string  you can pass space, new line, or any other characters like slash , backslash etc.

```
  example:      string path = @"\"C:\\My Folder\"";

          string name = @" sudhansu    sekhar";
```

Comment: note the @ symbol which is used to differentiate between normal string and delimited string