# C# Command line argument

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

We have developed a program that generates payment links here we have an issues the arguments are passed by command line arguments but if the string of the arguments contain a space it jumps to the next field.

Can we do the following to fix this? If so how?

```
-Amount "agument with space 1"
-Currency "argument with space2"
-Firstname "argument with space3"
...
```

this is the current bit of code:

```
if (commandlineargs.Length > 0)
                {
                    var BEDRAG = commandlineargs[1];
                    var CURRECY = commandlineargs[2];
                    var VOORNAAM = commandlineargs[3]; 

                    var ACHTERNAAM = commandlineargs[4];
                    var EMAIL = commandlineargs[5];
                    var KLANTCODE_EN_DOCNUM = commandlineargs[6];
                    var WINKEL = commandlineargs[7]; // (see sap configuration U_webshop)                  


                    txt_bedrag.Text = BEDRAG;
                    txt_firstname.Text = VOORNAAM;
                    txt_lastname.Text = ACHTERNAAM;
                    txt_email.Text = EMAIL;
                    txt_klant_en_docnummer.Text = KLANTCODE_EN_DOCNUM;
                    txt_currency.Text = CURRECY;
```

Comment: I suppose the shell does handle double quotes to that end just fine. cause that's what OS do to pass long paths, too. should work, did you try, and what happened?

Comment: I highly recommend you use either a command line parse (like [commandline](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline)) or a full blown CLI framework (like [CliFx](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/CliFx)) to save yourself a few headaches of having to properly parse command line arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the argument in double quotes:

```
-Amount "\"agument with space 1\""
```

Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085023/how-to-pass-a-string-with-spaces-in-it-as-start-arguments-for-a-program) for more details.

Comment: don't understand. how is this different from what OP suggested in the question? basically you're showing one of the ways of how to escape a double quote in a C# string literal here.